# Dart/Flutter Inheritance vs. Composition

Tags: flutter, dart, inheritance

I am making an app where I have a board which is a list of Tiles. Tile itself extends StatelessWidget due to almost every tile being unchanging. There is one type of tile, a LetterTile I would like to occasionally run animations (like at the start of a players turn) the main solution I had was to toggle a boolean that triggered the animation to begin. The issue with this is the LetterTiles are stateless due to them inheriting Tile. I know dart does not support multiple inheritance so I cannot extend Tile and StatefulWidget. What is the best practice to solve an issue like this?

TLDR I'm trying to take advantage of polymorphism by having a list of Tiles, which Tile is stateless. I need one type of tile to be Stateful due to starting and stopping animations.

Comment: Would mixins work for you?  https://dart.dev/language/mixins